# Django fails to process ManyToMany form field within view to create and save new model instance

Tags: python, django

I have two Models with a ManyToMany relationship. In my view I want to process the user input of the MultipleChoicesField and assign the selected choices to the Poller object.

It raises the following error:

> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is
> prohibited. Use poller_categories.set() instead.

**Models.py**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    poller_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    poller_category_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.poller_category)


class Pollers(models.Model):

    [..]

    # Poller Category
    poller_categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.poller_id)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class PollersForm(forms.Form):

    [..]

    # Poller Tags
    poller_categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())
```

**views.py**

```
def raise_poller(request):
        # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
        if request.method == 'POST':

            # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
            form = PollersForm(request.POST)

            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required

                poller_nature = form.cleaned_data['poller_nature']
                poller_text = form.cleaned_data['poller_text']
                poller_choice_one = form.cleaned_data['poller_choice_one']
                poller_choice_two = form.cleaned_data['poller_choice_two']
                poller_categories = form.cleaned_data['poller_categories']

                # Get the user
                created_by = request.user

                # Save the poller to the database
                p = Pollers(poller_nature = poller_nature,
                            poller_text = poller_text,
                            poller_choice_one = poller_choice_one,
                            poller_choice_two = poller_choice_two,
                            poller_categories = poller_categories,    # here seems to be my issue?
                            created_by = created_by)
                p.save()

                # redirect to a new URL:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly assign a value to the `poller_categies`. You should first save the `Pollers` object to the database, and then use `p.poller_categories.set(…)` to populate the many-to-many: relation

```
p = Pollers(
    poller_nature = poller_nature,
    poller_text = poller_text,
    poller_choice_one = poller_choice_one,
    poller_choice_two = poller_choice_two,
    # no poller_categories,
    created_by = created_by
)
p.save()
p.poller_categories.set(poller_categories)
```

The basic reason for this is likely that you need the primary key of *both* objects before you can link two items together, so at that moment there is not (yet) a record in the database for `p`.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks Willem! One question since I'm pretty new to M2M relationships: So a queryset of the Pollers table by Category "X" would only return all entries that have X (and possibly more) category assigned?

Comment: @Jonas: yes, you can retrieve the `Pollers` that have category `'X'` as one of the categories (there can be more, or only that category), with `Pollers.objects.filter(poller_categories__poller_category='X')`.

Comment: If you want to add extra categories to an already existing `Pollers` and you do not want to remove the current ones, you can work with `p.poller_categories.add(cat1, cat2)` with `cat1` and `cat2`, two `Categories` objects.

Comment: Nice, thanks! What do you mean with "primary keys of both objects"? Are those populated in another table out of my scope which is handled by Django in the background?

Comment: @Jonas: Django will for a many-to-many relation create an extra table with two `ForeignKey`s to the source model (here `Pollers`) and the target model (here `Categories`), this acts as a [*junction table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) between the two.